# shared memory with fork()

Tags: c, unix

I would like to use shared memory with `fork()` but I can't seem to get the result I want.

So I have a car Structure array and I would like to put it in shared memory in order to use `fork()`. Then I want to run 10 `fork()` and wait until all the kids are done to display the results! (the result is just their total time of each car, it is different because I am generating a random number for each car).

The problem is when I `printf()` I have the same value for everyone, whereas it must be different for each child! because i tested with just a loop so without shared memory it works fine but i have to use shared memory;).

Could anyone help me please

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define NUMBER_OF_CARS 10
#define MIN 25000 // time generator
#define MAX 40000

typedef struct {
    unsigned int totalTime;
} car;

car *shared_memory;

int drive(int i);
unsigned int generateNumber(void);
void display();

int main(void)
{
    srand( time(NULL) );
    
/***************************************************
*           Creating shared memory        *
****************************************************/
    int segment_id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(car) * NUMBER_OF_CARS, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    if (segment_id == -1) {
        perror("shmget() failed !");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    shared_memory = shmat(segment_id, NULL, 0);
    if (shared_memory == (void *) (-1)) {
        perror("shmat() failed !");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    /**********************************************************
     *               Creation of child / cars              *
     **********************************************************/
    int i;
    pid_t pid = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CARS; i++) {
        pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0)
            break;
    }

    switch (pid) {
        case -1:
            perror("fork failed !");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

        case 0:
            drive(i); //540000
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

        default:
            display();
            /********  wait for children to finish  *********/
            for (int j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_CARS; j++) {
                wait(NULL);
            }
    }

    /********  Detach memory segments  *********/
    shmdt(shared_memory);
    /********  Delete shared memory  *********/
    shmctl(segment_id, IPC_RMID, NULL);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

unsigned int timeMaxi = 540000;

int drive( int i ) {
    unsigned int number;
    while ( shared_memory[i].totalTime <= timeMaxi ) //time pas dépassée
    {
        number = generateNumber();
        shared_memory[i].totalTime += number;
    }
    return 0;
}

void display(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CARS; i++){
            printf("Total %d : %d\n", i, shared_memory[i].totalTime);
    }
}

unsigned int generateNumber(void)
{
    return rand()%(MAX-MIN+1)+MIN;
}
```

The result :

```
./prog
Total 0 : 564634
Total 1 : 564634
Total 2 : 564634
Total 3 : 564634
Total 4 : 564634
Total 5 : 564634
Total 6 : 564634
Total 7 : 564634
Total 8 : 564634
Total 9 : 564634
```

Comment: You shouldn't call `display()` until all the children have finished. You're printing before they write to the shared memory.

Comment: still the same problem, I called the function outside of the condition but nothing changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your shared memory. The problem is that all of the children are ending up with the same random number sequence in `generateNumber()`. You're only calling `srand()` once, before all the forks, so every child is going to generate the exact same random number.

Just call `srand()` in each child before calling `drive()`. `srand(time(NULL))` won't be enough, because they'll likely all run within the same second, but you could use `getpid()` or some other appropriate method as an argument to `srand()` to seed the random number generator in each child differently.